# Tag Edit queue is full and has been for several days

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, editing, review-queue

Saving Tag Info edits has been showing the error message "The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!" for several days now, which is quite a few minutes.

If this isn't something that somehow affects only me, could something be done about this?

Comment: I just tried to suggest a tag info edit, and I got the same message you did.  So, it's not just you.

Comment: Corresponding bug report on MSE: [It is now impossible to make a suggested edit to a tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387154/335251)

Comment: This issue is now fixed. See [KyleMit's answer to this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387320/335251) for details.